# If a wizard has a familiar and the feat Eldritch Heritage for the Arcane bloodline, what level do you use to determine the powers of the familiar?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, class-feature, wizard, familiars

If a [wizard](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizARD/#Arcane_Bond_Ex_or_Sp) has a familiar and the feat [Eldritch Heritage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eldritch-heritage/) for the [Arcane bloodline](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/arcane-bloodline/), what level do you use to determine the powers of the familiar?

The bloodline grants:

> ...you gain an arcane bond, as a wizard equal to your sorcerer level.
>   Your sorcerer levels stack with any wizard levels you possess when
>   determining the powers of your familiar or bonded object.

Eldritch Heritage says:

> For purposes of using that power, treat your sorcerer level as equal to your character level – 2.

If a wizard is level 10, then it's effective sorcerer level is 8. Does this mean the level used for determining the familiar's abilities is 18?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The levels stack.

If we look at [Eldritch Heritage](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Eldritch%20Heritage) it says:

> Select one sorcerer bloodline. You must have Skill focus in the class skill that bloodline grants to a sorcerer at 1st level (for example, Heal for the celestial bloodline). This bloodline cannot be a bloodline you already have. **You gain the first-level bloodline power for the selected bloodline. For purposes of using that power, treat your sorcerer level as equal to your character level – 2, even if you have levels in sorcerer.** You do not gain any of the other bloodline abilities.

If we then look at the [Arcane Bloodline](https://aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Arcane), it states:

> Arcane Bond (Su): At 1st level, you gain an arcane bond, as a wizard equal to your sorcerer level. **Your sorcerer levels stack with any wizard levels you possess when determining the powers of your familiar or bonded object. This ability does not allow you to have both a familiar and a bonded item.**

This means that your effective sorcerer levels gained from Eldritch Heritage stack with any wizard levels you have for determining the abilities of your [Arcane Bond](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizARD/#Arcane_Bond_Ex_or_Sp) essentially.

So a level 11 wizard with Elritch Heritage (Arcane) that had selected a Familiar for their arcane bond, would determine the abilities of their Familiar as if they were level 20.