# How do you progress your familiar without taking more levels in that class?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars, character-advancement

I am playing a [cleric](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric)/[wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard)/[Mystic Theurge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/mystic-theurge). I choose the familiar class feature for my wizard. MT only progresses a wizards spell casting and caster level. You do not learn new spells and the familiar does not gain increased abilities according to the [familiar chart](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Wizard/familiar/#Familiar_Ability_Descriptions).

Is there a way to improve the familiar according to the chart without taking levels in a class that grant a familiar? I mostly want the ability to speak with it at level 5, and the all important spell resistant at 11th (which gets better the higher level I am).

The Iron Will/Familiar Bond/[Improved Familiar Bond](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar-bond/) is not the route I wish to go because it requires way too many feats and Im already feat starved.

I know of [Boon Companion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/boon-companion/), but that increases the total by 4, which helps (more so once I can get SR).

Answer (score 4):

## 1. [Wasp Familiar](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wasp%20Familiar):

This feat grants you a familiar using your character level as your level for it.

## 2. [Skill Focus](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Skill%20Focus)/[Eldritch Heritage](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Eldritch%20Heritage) ([Arcane Bloodline](https://aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Arcane))

Detailed more closely [in this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154528), Eldritch Heritage (Arcane Bloodline) would increase the effective level of your familiar.

## 3. [Iron Will](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Iron%20Will)/[Familiar Bond](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Familiar%20Bond)/[Improved Familiar Bond](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Improved%20Familiar%20Bond)

I know you'd rather not go with this, but it is a way to get a familiar that progresses with your level.

## Honorable Mention: [Boon Companion](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Boon%20Companion)

This feat does not give you a scaling familiar, however it does increases your familiars effective level by 4.